Но поскольку - нужна ли запятая в данном случае?
Но (,) поскольку я все еще ждала ответа, ей пришлось что-то говорить.

Выбираем вариант без запятой:
Но поскольку я все еще ждала отвЕта, ей пришлось что-то говорИть.
Пояснение
В правилах Розенталя допускаются оба варианта, но чаще запятой нет. В предложении две фонетические фразы, разделенные паузой.
При постановке запятой вставочная интонация подчеркивает значимость придаточного, если в этом есть необходимость.
Розенталь § 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов.
3) после союза НО запятая ставится при наличии паузы между 
союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет; ср.: Но, если далее 
противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова 
бросалась в атаку (Сим.); Но когда он, опираясь на палку, 
вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… и, не ожидая, пока 
его обнимут, сам стал обнимать и целовать всех, кто попадал 
в его объятия, что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);


Но, поскольку я все еще ждала ответа, ей пришлось что-то говорить.
§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов
